# handling modal dialog in watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I try to make a test script for automated test using watir. and i have a problem that when i click the link to show the modal dialog but it cant find the element in the modal dialog.(eg: Dropdownlist element).

I already tried like this but it's not working.

browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end

what method that i can use so that it can find the field that we try to test the input when the active page is modaldialog? Please help me..

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to set the browser if you believe the title is throwing it off:

`browser.window(:index => 1).use`

Otherwise, I would suggest the following:

```
modal = browser.modal_dialog
modal.button(:id => 'close').click
```

or

`modal.link(:text => 'close').click`

Once you set the modal to `modal` you can call any methods you would normally call on a browser.

Comment: i have try your answer, but i got this error message says that C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/elemen
t.rb:328:in `assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["selec
t"], :id=>"ctl00_m_g_8f040f77_8a11_4762_a6b0_500e731fb4ed_ff19_1_ctl00_DropDownC
hoice"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException):id=>"ctl00_m_g_8f040f77_8a11_4762_a6b0_500e731fb4ed_ff19_1_ctl00_DropDownC
hoice"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: There could be several things that cause that error. The error stems from `watir` not being able to locate your element. It could be that you need to call `.when_present` on the element to allow it to load, or the element is within a frame and you need to specify that. You could be specifying the wrong element type (`button` vs `link`). There could be any number of issues, but without seeing the code it's hard to determine your exact case.